# Can we process large zip file in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, file-io, concurrency, spring-batch

I have a large zip file of size in GB. Inside of it there will be thousands of flat file. Currently we have single threaded application in place. We would like to improve performance by applying concurrency. I believe its to expensive to do concurrency on file I/O. Following are the functionalities

1. Unzip zip file to some location
2. Within that process each flat file and do some db inserts like inserting file information on some DB tables
3. Move file to archive once its processed

Since these are series of steps, Can we use Spring batching? Is it possible to do above sequential steps in Spring batching? Anyone please suggest if there is any existing framework or application to refer concurrency on File I/O operations.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: My experience with processing zip files is to not unzip them in the file system but instead read them with an instance of *ZipInputStream* (in Java) or a similar class for other languages. This already saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

With the requirement above, absolutely you can build a SpringBatch based application as below:

1. Partitioner level (You can utilize grid-size)

You will unzip the file and create 1 Execution Context for each of flat file extracted from the zip.

2. Reader level

You can use ItemFileReader or your custom Reader to read flat files.

3. Processor level

You can process items which sent from Reader.

4. Writer level

You can set commit-interval to control how to write to DB.

Thanks,
Nghia